# Multiple tag value in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-iam, aws-policies

It is possible to set multiple value in a `aws:PrincipalTag` for IAM policy ?

Currently, I have federated users with a `project` attribute ​​in their JWT and
depending on this value ​​I can give access to a specific "folders" in my s3 bucket.

For a JWT with following value:

```
"https://aws.amazon.com/tags": {
    "principal_tags": {
        "project": [
            "foo"
        ]
    }
}
```

and my AWS policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TagBasedAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myawesomebucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "${aws:PrincipalTag/project}/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It grant user access to `arn:aws:s3:::myawesomebucket/foo/` with success.

Now I will make it work for multiple values ​​in the `project` attribute (give access to multiple s3 "folder"). But I have no idea how to perform this.

EDIT:

in AWS documentation ([AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_tags.html)):

> you can include multiple values in a single tag with a custom
> separator. In this example, you could attach the `team = Engineering:QA`
> tag to Zhang.
> To control access to engineers in this example using the team
> tag, you must create a policy that allows for every configuration that
> might include `Engineering`, including `Engineering:QA`

but they dont say how to perform this...

Answer (score 0):

There is an AWS document relating to this question:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multi-key-or-value-conditions

Direct quote from the document:

> To compare your condition against a request context with multiple key values, you must use the **ForAllValues** or **ForAnyValue** set operators. These qualifiers add set-operation functionality to the condition operator so that you can test multiple request values against multiple condition values. Additionally, if you include a multivalued key in your policy with a wildcard or a variable, you must also use the **StringLike** condition operator.

Please refer the original documents for more information. You might want to know, for example, how condition operators and condition blocks work in this context.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and write a brief summary of the content of the link you provide. Remember that such content may no longer be available at later. Read [answer].

Comment: The question stated that it isn't a multiple key values, but multiple values in a single tag. Since the docs mentioned that `Do not use set operators with single-valued condition keys.`, I doubt this will works. Can you provide a working example if you have any?